# How to programmatically add attributes to a view in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I would like to programmatically add all the listed properties/ attributes to the EditText class object in Xamarin.
For example in XML :

```
<EditText
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:id="@+id/test"/>
```

What I have tried:

```
var editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setWidth(pixels)//I want match_parent here
```

rest attributes I am not able to found. Any insight would be much valued.

Comment: typically Android `setX` methods are exposed as C# `X` properties - so you would use `editText.Width = value`

Comment: Also how can i set the layout_weight?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+layout_weight+code+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: What does `The number of items are unforeseen` mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier in Xamarin. You just need to set the LayoutOptions Property.
Fill or FillAndExpand will try set the width/height of the item to the height of the parent. I recommend using Xaml which will work with live preview and you can change the xaml and see the changes reflect immediately.

```
Content = new StackLayout
{
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0),
    Children = {
    ...
    new Label { Text = "Start", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start },
    new Label { Text = "Center", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center },
    new Label { Text = "End", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End },
    new Label { Text = "Fill", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill }
    }
};
```

Check out the documentation for more examples and details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options